# Symmetric property of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices

Are symmetric matrices symmetric about a particular axis geometrically ? Or is the property defined only for the matrix representation of the linear transformation?
If you consider a unit square, after transformation due to a symmetric matrix, is  the resulting shape symmetric along any axis?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the word "symmetric" in "symmetric matrices" refers to what pancini talks about: the symmetry of the numbers in the matrix along the diagonal.

However, (real) symmetric matrices have nice geometric properties, which you could arguably connect to a kind of geometric symmetry. Symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalisable, meaning that they admit an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, and all its eigenvalues are real. Depending on where you are in your linear algebra studies, this may contain some concepts about which you may be unfamiliar, but let me try to describe what it means geometrically without going to deeply into the concepts.

Imagine the unit ball in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and we multiply each vector in the unit ball by a given matrix. Perhaps the ball will be stretched/compressed/flipped along an axis. Perhaps the matrix will rotate the ball. Perhaps there will be a skewing operation. Perhaps, all of the above will happen. Either which way, the resulting shape must be an ellipsoid.

When the matrix is symmetric, the ball will only be stretched/compressed/flipped along various axes. In fact, these axes will all be orthogonal, just like the usual axes, but possibly rotated to some other configuration. There will be no rotation involved; any vector along these axes will remain a vector along these axes.

In this way, this gives the geometric action of our symmetric matrix on the ball a bit of symmetry itself. If we slice the ellipse perpendicular to one of these orthogonal axes, then the action of the matrix on one side of the slice will mirror the action on the other side of the slice.

But, again, this is not the symmetry to which "symmetric matrices" refers.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetric matrices are symmetric about the main diagonal—that is, $A$ is symmetric iff $A=A^T$. It turns out that this property actually doesn't depend on the choice of basis under certain conditions (eg, over $\Bbb R$ with any orthonormal basis with respect to a given inner product). One way to see this is that $A=A^T$ is equivalent to the statement that the corresponding linear map is self-adjoint.

Comment: I mean geometrically. If you consider a unit square after transformation due to a symmetric matrix it the resulting shape symmetric along any axis?

Comment: The image of the the unit square under any matrix will be either a point, a line segment, or a parallelogram, which all have symmetries.

Comment: About which axis? Does the name symmetric mean anything geometrically?

Answer (score 1):

Let $s$ be a symmetry in $\mathbb R^2$. It is clear that $s^2=id_{\mathbb R^2}$.
Let $A:=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$
$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}
10 &  9\\
 9& 13
\end{bmatrix}\neq\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
The interest of symmetric matrices is related to the theorem: a bilinear form is symmetric if and only if its matrix is symmetric.
For example, $f:\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R, ((x,y),(x',y'))\mapsto xx'+3xy'+3x'y+2yy'$ is symmetric, ie$$\forall X=(x,y),Y=(x',y'), f(X,Y)=f(Y,X)$$
The same goes for $g(X,Y)=xx'-yy'+xy'+x'y$. Its matrix is $B:=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$
We have $$g(X,Y)=X^TBY=\left\langle X|BY\right\rangle=\left\langle BX|Y\right\rangle$$ where $\left\langle .|.\right\rangle $ is the dot product. If we now look at the self-adjoint endomorphism represented by B, here is for example its effect on a figure
[image]
$C=(9,1)\mapsto C"=(10,8)$...
I will not dwell further on this geometrical aspect since it has been mentioned in the other answers.